# Where is Package menu item in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, solution-package

I'm using visual studio 2012 for developing SharePoint 2010 solutions, back in vs2010 there was a menu item names "Package" so I can get the package without deploying it and I noticed it's disappeared from vs2012.

Can anyone guide me where can I find it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's called "Publish" now. Functionality is basically the same.